# Como ignorar o aviso de segurança

Tags: vb.net

Olá. Venho desenvolvendo um programa em vb.net, e no mesmo, há um "launcher" que baixa outros 2 programas e depois os executa. O problema é que ele dá o seguinte "erro" ao tentar executar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os 2 outros programas que o launcher executa necessitam de permissão de administrador. Porém, o launcher já é executado com esta permissão, e o código usado para executar esses outros 2 programas é feito com verb "runas" :

```
Dim Dir As String = "C:\Users\" & SystemInformation.UserName & "\AppData\LocalLow\Temp\abcde\"

Dim p As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(Dir & "Program.exe")
        p.Verb = "runas"
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(p)
```

Porém, do mesmo jeito, esse aviso continua sendo exibido. Poderiam me ajudar?

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 3):

Esse aviso é do UAC do Windows, e quando acha que a aplicacao é insegura ele da esse aviso, e o seu executavel tambem esta sem certificado, para resolver esse aviso, voce pode, Comprar um Certificado de Assinatura de Executaveis(chama-se de Certificado de CodeSign),
e assinar seu exe, nao ficara mas como desconhecido! ou Desativar teu UAC(mas so vai resolver esse aviso para vc).